# Underline specific letter of the Persian or Arabic word with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to underline specific letters of the words based on key down in html web page.
For example when user press Alt key I want under line `ت` in the word `تماس با ما`,
But when I tried to do this; the letter `ت` is Separated from the word `تماس` and shown as `ت ماس` as you know this is must be shown as `تماس` where `ت` is highlighted with underline.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UnderlineElementsBasedOnId(underline) {
        var id = "#" + underline;
        //        $(id).css(
        //            { 'text-decoration': 'underline' }
        //            );
        $(id).addClass('underline');
    }

    function UnderlineElementsBasedOnClass(undrrline) {
        var id = "." + undrrline;
        $(id).addClass('underline');
    };

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which === 18) {
                UnderlineElementsBasedOnClass("underlineClass");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```css
.underline {
     text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span><span class="underlineClass">ع</span>نصر اول</span></td>
            <td><span class="underlineClass">م</span>کتابات</td>
            <td><span class="underlineClass">ز</span>یر سیستم</td>
            <td><span class="underlineClass">م</span>الی</td>
            <td><span class="underlineClass">I</span>nfrastruture</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could you show your js-code so far?

Comment: Can you show the related jQuery codes?

Comment: This is not an appropriate place to put your code, edit your question to nicely explain what effort have you done so far..

Comment: what css rules you have used in `underlineClass` ??

Comment: As you can see in the js code, when All key is pressed,  UnderlineElementsBasedOnClass function tag all element with underlineClass  with "underline" in css, that simplify set text-decoration with underline tag